# how to convert timestamp value to date format in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a date value which is like timestamp format in database.

**below is tstamp column in one table:**

```
tstamp
1524141456
1536456847
```

I'm trying to get timestamp in date format how can I convert into date format?

Please help me.

**Below is my code:**

**controller:**

i wrote a query to get tstamp.below is the value

```
 $dta['submittimestamp']    = $test->tstamp;
    $data['records'] = $final_data;
```

**View:**

to echo the timestamp.
     `<td> <?php echo ucfirst($record->tstamp); ?> </td`>

> when i echo this am getting result like 1525464564 but i need it in
>   date

format
 when i echo this am getting result like 1525464564 but i need it in date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a PHP date function.

echo $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$record->tstamp);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a date function.

```
$date = date('l Y/m/d H:i', $record->tstamp);
echo $date;
```